# Tier 2 dependent visa

Tags: residency, uk-visa

Hi all my immigration expert buddies,

I am a doctor by profession and staying in the uk in tier 2 spouse visa with work permit ( restricted, no training facility ) for the last 3 months. I got a job of my own and i can work with my tier 2 spouse visa. But when I plan to apply for a training post, I have to change it. I need to learn a few things from anyone expert in this regard.

1. If I have to change my visa status from Tier 2 spouse to Tier 2 general for training purpose, the time I spent in spouse visa will be counted for ILR or it will start from the begining?
2. Can an organization apply for a COS for an employee in the middle of the contract? For example, I am not taking COS from my hospital now. Can I ask for it any time after I join?
3. Do I have to keep £ 945 in my bank account for 3 months to change my visa type even if the hospital is an A rated sponsor?

Thanks . This group has always been helpful to me. Hope this time I get some help regarding my queries.

Comment: Why do you say you have to change your visa? Is this some requirement of the employer? Seems odd, as your dependent visa should be suitable enough for just about any position not requiring citizenship.

Comment: @ouflak I can't find a government statement on this, but other sites (employment-related) state that there's a restriction on tier 2 dependant visas that the person can't work as a doctor or dentist in training.

Comment: From what I gather, you should be able to get a sponsored Tier 2 COS/visa easily enough [depending on your background and portfolio](https://www.immigrationboards.com/uk-tier-2-employer-sponsored-visas/does-nhs-sponsor-doctors-on-tier-2-dependant-visa-t170803.html#p1076233) of work in the UK. I'm not an expert, but I will put something together in an answer with what I've found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some good information [here on the British Medical Association](https://www.bma.org.uk/advice/employment/immigration/guide-to-uk-immigration/training-in-the-uk) website. I'll try to summarize, but have a good look through there.

1. Your ILR for each category (PBS dependent, PBS general, etc...) 'clock' will reset everytime you switch, but your 10 year ILR clock will continue as long as you are able to meet the residency requirements.
2. Yes, but you will have to go through the hurdles of switching visa types. This may mean leaving the country and applying from abroad.
3. From the [UK.gov Tier 2 website](https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-general/eligibility) (at the bottom in fine print):

> You won't need savings if you have both a fully approved (‘A-rated’) sponsor AND a certificate of sponsorship stating that your sponsor will give you at least £945 to cover your costs for a month if you need it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was a little worried about the process. Now I will join the hospital and  after a few weeks I am going to apply for my visa. I have heard from my colleagues that I can apply from UK .  If it is true, then I will not need to apply for the visa from my country. Thanks again. God bless.

Comment: If you think the answer actually answers your question, please select it as an answer as this helps guide others visiting this site for similar queries. I believe your colleagues are wrong, but there may yet be some special exception for medical professions (along with the other obvious exceptions) that I'm simply not aware of.